# RavenDb Mini Profiler only loads on the first page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, ravendb, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying the get the mini profiler for RavenDb running in my ASP.NET MVC4 project.

I have the following in my Unity bootstrapper:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Web.App.App_Start.AppStart_Unity), "Start")]
public static class AppStart_Unity
{
    public static void RegisterServices(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterInstance(DocumentStoreFactory.Create(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name));
        container.RegisterType<IDocumentSession>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name)));
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        // Create the unity container
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        // Register services with our Unity container
        RegisterServices(container);

        // Tell ASP.NET MVC to use our Unity DI container
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityServiceLocator(container));

        // hook up the profiler    
        var store = container.Resolve<IDocumentStore>();
        var documentStore = store as DocumentStore;
        if (documentStore != null)
        {
            Raven.Client.MvcIntegration.RavenProfiler.InitializeFor(documentStore);
        }
    }
}
```

In my master _Layout I have the following:

```
<head>
    @Raven.Client.MvcIntegration.RavenProfiler.CurrentRequestSessions()
</head>
```

The first time I start up the web application I can see the profiler, no problem.

However, any subsequent page requests and the profiler is not visible.

When I look at the page source, I can see the div container is there, but unpopulated with data. No JavaScript errors at all. Very odd. The HTML rendered looks like this:

```
<div class="ravendb-profiler-results">
    <div id="ravendb-session-container"></div>
    <p></p>
    <a href="#" class="ravendb-toggle ravendb-close">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comparing the requests, I see these requests in the first load:

1. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=yepnope.js`
2. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=jquery.tmpl.min.js`
3. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=ravendb-profiler-scripts.js`
4. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=jquery.tmpl.min.js`
5. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=ravendb-profiler-scripts.js`
6. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=Templates%2Ftotals.tmpl.html`
7. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=Templates%2Fravendb-profiler.tmpl.html`
8. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=Templates%2Fsession-template.tmpl.html`
9. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=Templates%2Frequest-details.tmpl.html`
10. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?id%5B%5D=d3ada4e4-4bc3-4a7c-bd36-64cc8017d94a`
11. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=styles.css`

In subsequent loads, I see the following requests:

1. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=yepnope.js`
2. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=jquery.tmpl.min.js`
3. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=ravendb-profiler-scripts.js`
4. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=jquery.tmpl.min.js`
5. `http://localhost:62238/ravendb/profiling?path=ravendb-profiler-scripts.js`

Oddly, I'm seeing duplicated calls **in both cases** for `jquery.tmpl.min.js` and `ravendb-profiler-scripts.js`.

The ravendb-profiler-scripts.js contains the line:

```
 9. var load = function () {
10. if (options.id.length == 0)
11.    return;
```

In the subsequent loads, options.id.length is zero. The templates then don't load, and the results are not fetched.

The first page load contains the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
yepnope([{ test: window.jQuery, nope: '/ravendb/profiling?path=jquery-1.6.1.min.js' }, { test: window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn.tmpl, nope: '/ravendb/profiling?path=jquery.tmpl.min.js' }, {load: '/ravendb/profiling?path=ravendb-profiler-scripts.js', complete: function() { jQuery(function() { RavenDBProfiler.initalize({ id:['df05238a-24a6-4a16-ad63-3b9537e9b544'], url: '/ravendb/profiling' }); }) } }]);
</script>
```

The subsequent loads contain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
yepnope([{ test: window.jQuery, nope: '/ravendb/profiling?path=jquery-1.6.1.min.js' }, { test: window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn.tmpl, nope: '/ravendb/profiling?path=jquery.tmpl.min.js' }, {load: '/ravendb/profiling?path=ravendb-profiler-scripts.js', complete: function() { jQuery(function() { RavenDBProfiler.initalize({ id:[], url: '/ravendb/profiling' }); }) } }]);
</script>
```

**Note the lack of *id* objects.**

I've also tried the [mini-profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) and I have also tried rolling back from the latest unstable RavenDb client to the current stable release. Nothing appears to make a difference.

Is this the expected behavior? Do I need to do anything else? Am I being an idiot here?

**Update**

I've just installed the Glimpse.Ravendb plugin and it reports:

> Profiling is currently not supported for EmbeddableDocumentStore.

However, I'm clearly not using the `EmbeddableDocumentStore`:

```
public static class DocumentStoreFactory
{
    public static IDocumentStore Create(string connectionStringName)
    {
        var documentStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = connectionStringName };
        documentStore.Initialize();
        documentStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists(connectionStringName);

        var catalog = new CompositionContainer(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Users_ByKarmaAndLocation).Assembly));
        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(catalog, documentStore.DatabaseCommands.ForDatabase(connectionStringName), documentStore.Conventions);

        return documentStore;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a red herring or not. Thought I would mention it though.

Comment: what's the connection string being used?

Comment: @synhershko <add name="project" connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8080" />

Comment: try adding "http://". if that doesn't work, can you come up with steps to reproduce and send them to the mailing list?

Comment: @synhershko Double checked. Makes no difference. Still first time load is fine. Subsequent, no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my Unity setup. I should not have used a Unity `HierarchicalLifetimeManager()` but a `PerResolveLifetimeManager()`. The Glimpse problem resolved once I had restarted the application.

With hindsight, I should have paid closer attention to the different types of LifetimeContainers and used them properly.

The updated Unity config looks like this:

```
public static class AppStart_Unity
{
    public static void RegisterServices(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterInstance(DocumentStoreFactory.Create(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name));
        //container.RegisterType<IDocumentSession>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name)));
        container.RegisterType<IDocumentSession>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession()));
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        // Create the unity container
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        // Register services with our Unity container
        RegisterServices(container);

        // Tell ASP.NET MVC to use our Unity DI container
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityServiceLocator(container));

        var store = container.Resolve<IDocumentStore>();
        var documentStore = store as DocumentStore;
        if (documentStore == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        RavenProfiler.InitializeFor(
            documentStore,
            "Email", "HashedPassword", "AkismetKey", "PasswordSalt", "UserHostAddress");
        Profiler.AttachTo(documentStore);
    }
}
```